# Apache POI Read Security Classification Excel files

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can anyone suggest, how to read the security classification(Internal, Confidential, Public) of MS Word/Excel files using Apache POI or any other API?

I could not find in Apache POI to extract this security classification (Internal, Confidential, Public).

most organizations have these labels for Office documents.

Comment: before I start digging, do you mean the extra information azure-information-protection (AIP) puts in or the default classification? (maybe its the same... idk yet). can you still unzip your (unencrypted) files? if so, do you find the classification as plain text in the xmls?

Comment: I've just tried it out with an AIP enabled Word instance - those properties are in the docProps/custom.xml file. So you would like to look at POIXMLDocument (XSSFWorkbook is an instance) -> getProperties() -> getCustomProperties() -> getProperty(...). In my custom.xml the property name is "MSIP_Label_6e9f6ef8-0c49-4ecd-9398-6ef8b9899224_Name" or use getUnderlyingProperties() to access the XmlBeans directly

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and help! Now I can extract the metadata CTProperties customProps = props.getCustomProperties().getUnderlyingProperties()