# How to identify Office documents sensitivity label in Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office

Using Apache POI library, I've manged to identify password protected documents. Now I would need to check for the sensitivity label (Confidential, Internal etc), which as far as I know is only available in OOXML format (docx, etc) and not the OLE2 (doc, ppt, etc)

While debugging, I searched through the properties/values of my POIXMLProperties instance but could not recognise anything about sensitivity.

```
 OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
 POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
```

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812284/apache-poi-read-security-classification-excel-files) but the answer was not much helpful.

Does anyone know the specific attribute name or values? Is it even possible to know such thing?

Comment: I doubt that will be possible. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-sensitivity-labels-to-your-files-and-email-2f96e7cd-d5a4-403b-8bd7-4cc636bae0f9#:~:text=Apply%20sensitivity%20labels%20to%20your%20files%20and%20email,website%20to%20explain%20more%20about%20their%20sensitivity%20labels. -> "Important:  Sensitivity is only available if: ..." Apache POI != Microsoft Office.